# How to cancel the image while uploading using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My Objective is to upload image, But here i'm facing one problem - I could upload Image but when i want to change the image and without changing any image, if i click cancel then i'm facing some error as **Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided**

Here is the code:

```
onImageChange = event => {
    let file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log("File", file);

    if (file === undefined) {
      console.log("File removed");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        img: file
      });
    }
  };
```

[here is the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-johnson-sx3vc)

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: @adel  -  Hi, I have update in my query. Could you please check it once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok easy solved, when clicking cancel you need to add if statement to check if `files.length>0`. So that how you now if user not selected a file than add default Avatar.

here the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
class AvatarDisplay extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      img: "/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
    };
  }

  onImageChange = event => {
    let file;
    console.log(event.target.files);
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      this.setState({
        img: file
      });
    } else
      this.setState({
        img: "/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          accept="image/*"
          id="contained-button-file"
          multiple
          type="file"
          onChange={this.onImageChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
          <Avatar src={this.state.img} width="250" height="250" />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AvatarDisplay;
```

and for working expample : [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-robinson-nsk2z?file=/src/Avatar.jsx:0-993)